Qemu - attempting to emulate Windows 10 with multiple cores
So I'm trying to get Qemu to use more cores on my Raspberry Pi 4b due to the poor performance on emulating Windows 10, but it seems to be using one of the cores, but not any others. I did use the -smp option, but that didn't work. I've tried solutions on the internet, but nothing is working. The same thing is happening to Windows 7 too when I attempt to emulate it. What am I missing? Is there some config I'm missing, or is it just impossible for the Raspberry Pi to do anything like that?
I am on the latest version of QEMU by the way (Referencing Answer here)
Command to run emulator:
qemu-system-x86_64 -M pc -m 4G -cpu qemu64 -smp sockets=1,cores=4,threads=4 -vga cirrus -device qemu-xhci -device usb-kbd -device usb-tablet -nic user,model=virtio-net-pci -vnc 0.0.0.0:2,websocket -drive file=meep.vhd,if=virtio,cache=writeback


I believe the -smp flag needs a number for CPUs after it, which I do not see in your example.  You should try -smp 4,sockets=1,cores=4,threads=1 and see if that uses more CPUs.

Tried that just now. Didn't notice any difference. It still isn't using all the cores I have. I'll update the command though.
